# Overlay an img on top of another img

Tags: html, css, css-position

In the following HTML, I want the small delete icon to appear in the upper left corner of its container (the div). The larger image (a cat) needs to be inside of the div and scale so that it does not exceed the height of the div. I need the div to float left because of how its used elsewhere. The delete icon is suppose to overlay on top of the larger image (if the larger image fills the width of the div). Please note, that the larger image may actually have a width that is much less than the div and it gets centered in the div. In this case, the delete icon, still is in the upper left corner but is not really overlaying on top of the larger image since the larger image would be too small. The width of the div always remains the same regardless of the width of the larger image.

Here is my html:

```
<div style="float:left; width:120px; height:90px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #c0c0c0">
    <img src="http://hellopune.mobi/site2/Images/icon_delete.png" />
    <img src="http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/100691619-what-is-cat-fostering-632x475.jpg" style="height:90px" />
</div>
```

And in fiddler:
http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/eJZ7X/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJZ7X/2/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

div img:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Here, am positioning the *delete* `img` to `absolute` with `top` and `right` properties, if you want `left` than you can do that too, and make sure you wrap them inside a `position: relative;` container.

---

> Note: Am using `first-of-type` pseudo so you do not have to alter your
>   DOM, but if you think that the order of the `img` might change than
>   better assign a `class` to the *delete* `img` instead.

---

As you feel my selectors are too generic, assume that you have a parent with a `class` called `.img_holder` and this will have `div` nested further and than you nest both the `img` inside that so your selector will be

```
.img_holder > div {
    position: relative;
}

.img_holder > div > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.img_holder > div > img:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

And the DOM would look like

```
<div class="img_holder">
    <div>
        <img src="#" />
        <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="#" />
        <img src="#" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="#" />
        <img src="#" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also get rid of a lot of the styling from the original fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/eJZ7X/3/

Comment: That looks like it. I can live with the delete button in the upper right instead. I'm still having a problem though. I'm not sure how to combine your CSS with the ones I've listed on each element. I need to use styles because I need to repeat that for multiple divs. You've written it to be very generic. Could you please move my styles to yours and give each a name. Sorry, but I'm kind of lost how to do that.

Comment: I tried using your updated version but the style classes never get applied. I'm using Google Chrome. Are you sure the syntax is correct? I'm not familiar with the ">" part in styles.

Comment: @AndroidDev that means direct child, and it will work 100% http://jsfiddle.net/W8Gzu/

Comment: I see where the difference is. You added an outer div that is not in my original code.

Comment: @AndroidDev That's why *Read what I explain :)*

Comment: I still see a problem. If I choose a smaller image, your code positions the image to the far left. I need the image to be centered horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @AndroidDev that wasn't the scope of your question, but anyways you can do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/W8Gzu/1/

Comment: @Mr.Alien Actually the centering was specified: " Please note, that the larger image may actually have a width that is much less than the div and it gets centered in the div." - But I managed to modify your code to get it to work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eJZ7X/1/)

The icon img now has an icon class and is absolute positioned in the div.

html:

```
<div style="float:left; width:120px; height:90px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #c0c0c0">
    <img class="icon" src="http://hellopune.mobi/site2/Images/icon_delete.png" />
    <img src="http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/100691619-what-is-cat-fostering-632x475.jpg" style="height:90px" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.icon {
    position: absolute;
}
```